# write string list into csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to put a list of string into csv, but in the output csv each letter is separated by comma. Is there a way to fix this?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen    
import csv
from scrapy.selector import Selector
def make_soup(url):
    data_text = urlopen(url).read()
    hxs = Selector(text=data_text)
    return hxs

hxs = make_soup("http://propinfo.co.lincoln.or.us/property-search?search=+NW+3RD+ST")
act = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/text()').extract()



with open("accounts.csv", "wb") as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    writer.writerows(act)
```

Comment: Why not just use another seperator then? Like tab or ;

Comment: then each letter is separated by tab or ;

Comment: This usually means you are passing a string where the CSV code expects a list. Try printing out your `act` variable and see what it looks like (probably a big blob of text) versus what you think it should look like (a table, a row, a pair of columns, a single paragraph). Then try to `split` or `dedent` or `[make a list]` or whatever you need to do.

Comment: This is because `act` is a string, not a list of strings. Convert it into a list of the strings you want comma-separated first.

Comment: can you post your input sample and expected output?

Comment: You didn't need to convert `act` to a list... it was already a list of strings. Add a print statement or two or even run `python -i myscript.py` so that you can see what your variables are. If you do, you'll find that `act` is a list of strings `[u'M14422', u'M28900', ...]`.  Strings are sequences, so when you try to `writerows`, the `csv` module comma-separates the items of the sequence. So, what do you want your csv to look like? Right now you have 1 column of data.

Answer (score 2):

Printing `act` shows that you have a list of strings `[u'M14422', u'M28900', u'M33698', ...]`. `writerows` treats each string in the list as a row, and that means that each character in the string is a column. That's why you end up with comma-separated characters in the finel csv.

The solution is to put each string into its own list so that the row is a list with a single column.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv
from scrapy.selector import Selector
def make_soup(url):
    data_text = urlopen(url).read()
    hxs = Selector(text=data_text)
    return hxs

hxs = make_soup("http://propinfo.co.lincoln.or.us/property-search?search=+NW+3RD+ST")
act = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/text()')

with open("accounts.csv", "wb") as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    for row in act:
        writer.writerow([row])
```